# Accuracy of combining multiple predictive tests

Tags: probability

Let’s say I have produced 100 neural network models that can predict the outcome of a binary event (for instance, whether it is going to rain tomorrow). The first model has a 51.25% accuracy, the second model has a 53.73% accuracy, the third model has a 52.68% accuracy, and so on......In total, the average accuracy across 100 models is 52%.

Let’s say the probability of whether it will rain tomorrow or not is 50%. I use all 100 models to make 100 individual predictions on whether it will rain tomorrow.

Since the average accuracy across 100 models is 52%, does that mean that 52% of the 100 predictions made will be correct, and 48% of the predictions will be wrong?

I’m only starting to learn probability and statistics, so forgive me if this answer is stupid, thanks!

Comment: You won't have exactly 52% of models being right all the time, but it could very well be the modal number of models being correct.

Comment: You also have to make the assumption that all model predictions are independent if you want to do any nice calculations. This is certainly not going to be the case in practice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's assume that each model makes predictions independently of each other. Secondly, let's simplify the problem to just 2 models.

We'll have model A is correct 51% of the time and model B correct 53% of the time - so an average of 52% accuracy.

Let A be the event that model A is correct, and B be the event that model B is correct.

$$P(A,B) = 0.51\times0.53 = 0.2703$$
$$P(A,B') = 0.51\times0.47 = 0.2397$$
$$P(A',B) = 0.49\times0.53 = 0.2597$$
$$P(A',B') = 0.49\times0.47 = 0.2303$$

So we have the probability of both models being correct as 0.2703, the probability of one model being correct is 0.4994 and the probability of both being wrong is 0.2303.

The same sort of logic would have to be applied with the exact numbers of your model accuracies, but you would end up with a small probability of exactly 52% of your models being correct, but definitely not 100%.

Let's suppose that each model was exactly 52% accurate. The probability of 52 out of 100 models being correct is $0.52^{52}0.48^{48}$ multiplied by how many ways that can happen which is $\binom{100}{52} = \frac{100!}{52!(100-52!)}$

$$\frac{100!}{52!(100-52!)} \times 0.52^{52} \times 0.48^{48} \approx 0.07965$$

We have about a 7.965% chance of exactly 52 being correct